# Cannot open Workbook in read/write mode

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply different macros to every excel file present in a folder adding several sheets to them, and to do so I'm looping over all the files in the folder and opening them one by one.

However, I stumbled upon the issue that, every workbook I open is in read only mode, thus preventing me from saving it after having modified it.

Setting the ReadOnly parameter to False, and the IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended parameter to True doesn't change anything, and the workbook still opens as a read only workbook.

```
Sub RunOnAllFilesInFolder()

    Dim folderName As String, fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    folderName = "H:\mypath"
    fileName = Dir(folderName & "\*.xlsx")
    Debug.Print (fileName)

    Do While fileName <> ""

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=folderName & "\" & fileName, ReadOnly:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)

        MsgBox (wb.ReadOnly)

        wb.Activate

        Call my_sub 

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        wb.SaveAs (folderName & "\" & fileName)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Set wb = Nothing 'clean up

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Debug.Print "Processed " & folderName & "\" & fileName
        fileName = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Would anyone know why the file opens as a read only file (despite being just a regular excel file), or another way to modify these files and save the changes?

Comment: Are you running Excel with administrator privileges? This seems like a permission problem rather than a VBA problem per se. Also, is your `H` drive a network drive (that could be relevant).

Comment: I'm on a work computer, so I do not have administrator privileges, are these required to modifiy files the way I do? I can open them and save them manually just fine.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but the discussion I found online about your problem points to these issues. See [this thread](https://www.makeuseof.com/answers/why-are-excel-files-opening-as-read-only/) for example. Maybe one of the solutions there might help.